# Serializing Related Entities

Tags: .net, web-services, entity-framework, asmx

I'm using the Entity Framework 4 to serialize an object via an XML web service. The scalar properties on the object serialize fine, and I have a 0 or 1 property which also serializes.

I have one property however which is omitted from the output. It's a one to many (My object has a List), but the Sections navigation property isn't even included in the output. I'm including the property in my linq query, and debugging shows that the items in the `Sections` property are indeed loading, just not serializing. Here's my code:

```
dim item = Db.Surveys.Include("SurveySections").FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.SurveyID = surveyId)
```

Comment: This must be an attribute I can set somewhere. If I add an alias for the property using a partial class everything is serialized as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by creating an additional property which acted like an extra getter/setter for the EF property.